# a good introduction to Laplace Beltrami operator over differential manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'd like to have a good reference to understand how the Laplacian operator get generalized over differential manifolds.

More concretely, I want to understand and prove the equation :
$$\Delta Id_{\mathbf{X}}=H.\mathbf{N}$$
Where $\mathbf{X}$ is a smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $Id_\mathbf{X}$ the identity function defined on $\mathbf{X}$, $H$ its mean curvature and $N$ the normal vector to the surface $\mathbf{X}$ (ie its Gaussian map).

I have read Andrew Pressley's book *Elementary Differential Geometry*.
I'm used to the classical Laplacian of differential calculus that operates on scalar fields, but I dont really understand what the Laplacian of a vector field represents, how it relates to the scalar version or how you define a Laplacian over manifolds.

I have not finished Pressley, but it does not seem to cover this topic.

But trying to look into it, I also saw lot of references to things like tensors, connection form, volum form, that I dont know.

If you have also good recommandation regarding those topics, I would be grateful.
Basically, I would like to understand how to do multivariable calculus over surfaces.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to clarify the notation? For example, what does $\Delta X$ mean for $X$ a smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I'm afraid you **do** have to learn "things like tensors, connection form, volume form". The Laplace operator and, especially, Laplace--Beltrami operators are parts of what is called Hodge theory. Probably, one can define $\Delta$ of a function on a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of coordinates (I never tried this), but such a definition would be pretty much meaningless (as any definition in terms of coordinates). The true definition $\Delta=dd^*+d^*d$ uses differential forms a lot, and it cannot be explained in just a few words.

Comment: Yan, I can't make sense of your equation as it is written. The $\Delta$ operator acts on functions (or differential forms), not on manifolds. Even assuming the LHS was $\Delta_X$ in the sense of "the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the manifold $X$", the RHS is not a differential operator but a vector field on $X$. So, please, clarify.

Comment: Or, maybe, $X$ is a map $X: \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\Delta X$ means "take the Euclidean Laplacian of each component of $X$ ", and the equation says you obtain the components of a vector field on the image of $X$ which is proportional to the normal vector field?

Comment: You are right, I was abusing notations.

Comment: Actually the LHS is the Laplacian applied on the identity function defined on $\mathbf{X}$ : $\Delta Id_{\mathbf{X}}$. In the material I have been using, $\mathbf{X}$ is the surface patch (so as you said, a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$), but it's also used to design the points of the manifold, and by extension the image of the identity function. Or at least that's how I understood it.

Comment: @Yan On a manifold, is not the Laplacian, simply, equal to "Divergence of Gradient" $Div\circ \nabla$? so we need only a  riemannain metric to define gradient and the corresponding volum form to define Div/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is rather standard notation which admittedly could be a bit confusing if you've never seen it before. In this equation $\Delta X$ has *nothing* to do with differential forms, all you need to know is the definition of the Laplacian for a submanifold. FYI, I think that my sign convention is different than yours.

Write $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and the normal vector $N=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$. All this equation claims is that for $\Sigma^2\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$,

$$\Delta_\Sigma x_i = -H n_i$$

for $i=1,2,3$. Here, we just mean that $x_i$ are the Euclidean coordinates, restricted to the surface. In particular, a often used consequence of this equation is that $\Sigma$ is a minimal surface if and only if $\Delta_\Sigma x_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3$.

---

To prove this, you need to know about the second fundamental form, and how it relates the Levi-Civita connection on $\Sigma$ with the Euclidean connection. Remember that 
$$
(D^\Sigma)_X Y = (D^{\mathbb{R}^3})_X Y + II(X,Y) N
$$
(I don't know exactly what notation you're used to, so feel free to ask for clarification). Also, everyone has different sign conventions here, so be careful.

Then, if $e_1,e_2$ is an orthonormal basis for $T_p\Sigma$, we can extend it to a neighborhood of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that it is parallel with respect to $D^{\mathbb{R}^3}$. Then, we compute:
\begin{align*}
\Delta_\Sigma x_i & = tr_{g_\Sigma}(D^\Sigma)^2 x_i\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^2 ((D^\Sigma)_{e_j}d x_i)(e_j) \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^2 ((D^\Sigma)_{e_j}(d x_i(e_j)) - dx_i((D^\Sigma)_{e_j}e_j)\\
& =  \sum_{j=1}^2 ((D^{\mathbb{R}^3})_{e_j} dx_i)(e_j) - dx_i((D^{\mathbb{R}^3})_{e_j}e_j) - II(e_j,e_j)dx_i(N)\\
& =- Hn_i
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailled answer. 
I know the 1st and 2nd fundamental forms and what they represent.
The problem is that I don't know what is the Levi Civita connection. I have seen the term several times, but it isn't cover by the book I'm reading.
When reading the wikipedia article, I see a lot of terme I am not familiar with (connection ? metric connection ? fiber/vector bundle ?)

That's why I am looking for a more formal introduction to the subject. But there is a huge number of books on the subject of differential geometry and I dont really know where to look.

Comment: A good textbook on differential geometry is what you need. There are several, and you should consult a few of them.

Comment: @Yan, one of my favorite is Lee "Riemannian Manifolds: Introduction to Curvature" http://www.amazon.com/Riemannian-Manifolds-Introduction-Curvature-Mathematics/dp/0387983228.

Comment: @Otis Lee's book states already in the introduction that it will not touch upon Laplace-Beltrami operator.

Answer (score 1):

Another neat proof I found recently: given $v \in \Bbb R^3$, define $h: \Sigma \to \Bbb R$ by $h(p) = \langle p,v\rangle$. On one hand, $\triangle h = \langle \triangle\iota, v\rangle$, where $\iota\colon \Sigma \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ is the inclusion, and on the other hand ${\rm Hess}\,h(X,Y) = \langle {\rm II}(X,Y),v\rangle$. Since $\triangle = \rm tr\; {\rm Hess}$, we obtain $\triangle h = \langle 2H, v\rangle$, where $H = {\rm tr}({\rm II})/2$ is the mean curvature vector field. Comparing, we obtain $\triangle \iota = 2H$.

This generalizes to isometric immersions $f:\Sigma^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^{n+m}_\nu$ giving $\triangle f = n H$, even when $\Sigma$ is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold.